# Jump to next error FILE in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for any way to navigate between errors in IntelliJ.

I know how to jump INSIDE one file. And I found a bunch of macros, editor extensions, etc. plugins to extend the functionality, but there seem to be nothing to help me in these scenarios:

I remove method from baseclass.
I hit rebuild, so nice, now 20 files have errors as expected.

Now I have to manually click either on the red error in the make info to open the file, or on the file in the project tree (marked red) to open the error file. Once inside the file its easy, F2, some ALT+ENTER, fixed.

So any way to jump TO NEXT ERROR FILE.
Or any way to navigate between (not open) files by keyboard. E.g. Open next file in tree structure, etc..

Comment: Are you using the Righ-Click->"Refactor"->"Safe Delete" (Alt+Delete) option in IntelliJ which lets you review all the errors that might be caused by deleting the specific method?

Comment: that would be an awesome feature... maybe I'll try to add it sometime...

http://bjorn.tipling.com/how-to-make-an-intellij-idea-plugin-in-30-minutes

Answer (score 15):

With IntelliJ 2017.2.2, <kbd>F2</kbd> is mapped to "Next Highlighted Error" per default. Make sure to **focus the Project editor first**. Similarly <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> is mapped to "Previous Highlighted Error". The mappings mentioned in the other answers do not work.

Comment: If you want to remap these keys, just go to File -> Preferences -> Keymap and search for "Highlighted Error" and you'll be shown the current maps and options to change them.

Answer (score 12):

I'm on WindowsXP, and I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> to navigate through the messages in the Make window - does this do what you want?

One thing about that though, is that it is actually navigating though "messages" not just errors - so if you have a lot of warnings in your project, that could get in the way.  I did just notice there's a "hide warnings" button though, so that could help.

Answer (score 4):

On Mac it is: ⌥ + ⌘ + ↓ (or ↑ for previous)

(Found this in the documentation thanks to @Shorn's answer for Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to the Project Editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>) and then press <kbd>F2</kbd> it jumps to the next file with an error.